# Using 'ilike' to select rows with backslash character [PostgreSQL]

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I try to execute such query:

```
select * from my_table where table_name ilike 'PDK\1100090'
```

this query returns 0 rows, but in fact that table contains a row with such string. I verified that by selecting everything from that table. I also used '=' instead of ilike, and tried esaping the string with E'PDK\1100090' with no luck. I assume there is a problem with a backslash in the string but I could be wrong about that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it supposed to be a literal backslash or an octal constant `e'PDK\x480090'` ? For a literal backslash,  `e'PDK\\1100090'` should do the trick.

Comment: The backslash have a special meaning in the `[i]like` queries: it is the default escape character (why? `%` and `_` meta-characters can be escaped with that). you could use `col_name ilike 'PDK\1100090' escape '!'` or `col_name ilike 'PDK\\1100090'` (assuming `standard_conforming_strings` is `on`; which is by default `on` from 9.1+).

Comment: @joop it is supposed to be a literal backslash

Sadly none of your suggestions worked guys, but anyways thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the query by adding 3 more backslashes solve the problem. Now it looks like this:

```
select * from my_table where table_name ilike 'PDK\\\\1100090'
```

Comment: Which is most probably caused by some "front end"  (eg shell script) performing the first level of backslash quoting; thus reducing the string to contain only two backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

You claim to have tried double back slashes.  Try this:

```
where table_name ilike 'PDK_1100090'
```

Does that return anything?  (The underscore should match any character in that position.)

Then try for any sequence:

```
where table_name ilike 'PDK%1100090'
```

Then look for unusual characters at the beginning/ending of the string:

```
where table_name ilike '%PDK%1100090%'
```

If the double backslash isn't working, then you have some other funkiness in the string.

Comment: Ok, thanks replacing backslash with ' _ ' works as expected. The problem I see is now it may return more rows than before. I also found out that adding 3 more backslashes solve the problem ('PDK\\\\1100090')

Comment: @DanoPlurana that just means that you have `standard_conforming_strings` setting turned off. Either you use a pre 9.1 version (which is getting really old; you should consider upgrading), or you  use that for backward-compatibility reasons (but that case, you should have mentioned it in the question).

Comment: Yup, I use pre 9.1 version. Although your answer doesn't fully solve the problem it is worth upvoting. Thanks !